# Rotating pauli matrices along an axis

Tags: vectors, spinors

In my research, I am working with Pauli matrices along a unit-vector $\mathbf{n}$. I need to find a general form of an axis of rotation and angles for a generic vector $\mathbf{n}=(n^x, n^y, n^z)$ such that ($\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma})\rightarrow \sigma^z$.

I used mathematica to work out a few special cases.

i) when $\mathbf{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$, I can rotate ($\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma})\rightarrow \sigma^z$ with axis of rotation $\mathbf{k}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$ and $\theta=\arccos(1/\sqrt{3})$.

i) when $\mathbf{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0)$, I can rotate ($\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma})\rightarrow \sigma^z$ with axis of rotation $\mathbf{k}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$ and $\theta=\pi/2$.

It seems like the axis of rotation $\mathbf{k}$, would be the same for the general case, but I need to find $\theta$ for the general case when $\mathbf{n}=(n^x, n^y, n^z)$ .

I couldn't use Mathematica solve for the general case. Can you suggest me a way to get the general form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any axis-and-angle-combination that rotates the unit vector $\mathbf{n}$ into the unit vector in the $z$-direction will work. For example, you can pick the axis to be $\mathbf{n}\times \hat{z}$ and the angle to be $\cos^{-1}(n_z)$.

In general, if you take a linear combination of the three generators of $SU(2)$ : $n_x \hat{L}_x + n_y \hat{L}_y + n_z \hat{L}_z$ and conjugate it with an $SU(2)$ group element $\hat{g}$, then $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ (now thought of as a unit vector in three dimensions) will get acted upon by an $SO(3)$ rotation $g'$ corresponding to the $SU(2)$ element $\hat{g}$.